# Alternative to 'apart from the purpose to'

Tags: phrase-request

Consider you want to contrast another purpose of your work with one you just mentioned. You could write for example:

> Apart from the purpose to validate ..., we also hope that ... .

What are other alternatives to this expression ?

Comment: Instead of using the infinitive, you could probably write, "Apart from [the purpose of] validation, …", with the part in brackets mostly optional. I would also consider starting with "In addition to…" rather than, "Apart from…".

Answer (score 1):

It might be more elegant to say "In addition to validating ... we hope to..."

Answer (score 0):

You can use also the form *not only .. but also*

We not only want to validate ... but also hope that..

Answer (score 0):

Consider using "besides" instead of "apart from."

> Besides validating..., we also hope that...